# Start Points on How to Build Audio File Stream iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, audio, stream, streaming, audio-streaming

I need some guidance on how to make a audio stream app for multiple audio files, so the app user can choose from the list and listen to the item. Can someon help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the **audio name** and **audio URL / PATH**.

Then display the list of **audio name** using table view or create custom list using scroll view.

Then, when user select any one of them then pass the selected **audio URL / PATH** to audio player controller.

Audio player will automatically stream the audio.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept on how it wood look like, i need something on how to pause and resume, how to go to next and previous are there some classes that can help me do this

Answer (score 0):

Study and integrate this project- https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer

Comment: This is to complicated. Do you know any good tutorials, or place from where i can learn how to do this by my self